# Tabs Iframe/Canvas on Facebook pages

Tags: facebook, iframe, canvas, tabs

I wanna add a tab on my Facebook page. This shows an error :

```
FBML Error (line 14): illegal tag "body" under "fb:tab-position"

Erreurs d'exécution :

URLExceptionInvalid scheme for url (javascript:history.back())
```

Nevertheless, Static FBML works great !

What can I do, please ?

Thanks

**Update :**

I don't understand your expression `body-tag` less.

> FBML Error (line 14): illegal tag
>   "body" under "fb:tab-position"
>
> FBML Error (line 116): illegal tag
>   "noscript" under "fb:tab-position"
>
> FBML Error (line 136): illegal tag
>   "noscript" under "fb:tab-position"

I deleted all `<body>` `<head>` `<html>` tag. There are only `div` tag

Answer (score 0):

FBML only supports a subset of HTML tags, the `body` tag is not supported. For a list of supported tags, see:

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FBML

So you should not use `body` tag in facebook **fbml** apps/pages.

Comment: I don't use FBML... I use Canvas / Iframe

Comment: @Steffi: Have you selected `iframe` setting from app developer settings? www.facebook.com/developers. Or are you including any file accidentally that hos body tag into it?

Comment: Yeah, I've selected 'iframe', I can see the apps runs : http://apps.facebook.com/steyffi-music/. But when I wanna add it in tab : FBML Error (line 14): illegal tag "body" under "fb:tab-position"

Answer (score 0):

What actually solved my problems today was a radio in App - Advanced (tab): **Page Tab iframe**: turn it to **enabled**.
Facebook tries to parse FBML by default as today (May 2012)